# correlation and regression - low variance

Tags: regression, correlation, variance

I'm looking at 4 pairs of independent variables and one dependent variable. The correlation analyses revealed no significant correlation, although it was positive, between all independent variables and the dependent variable. Is it bad that my correlation coefficients were not significant?

The regression analyses revealed significant coefficients, but they were quite low, all between .100-.200. I calculated R squared which gives me very low variance, from 7% to less than 1%. what does this mean? Is my analysis just not useful?

The independent variables were 4 different factors of 2 different marketing strategies and the dependent variable was purchasing decisions, so I was thinking maybe there is low variance because purchasing decisions are influenced by many other things apart from those factors of the marketing strategies or even marketing strategies in general, e.g. also influenced by price, product type/quality etc. Not sure if this makes sense though..

NOTE: My study aims to compare the 2 marketing strategies, so im not even sure that variance is that important in my situation. I am looking to see which marketing strategy is the most effective, so should I just focus on which one has the higher coefficients?